# Legend layer - displayed on each tileWMS (OpenLayers)

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, legend

I have a strange symptom when add legend to layer WMS (OpenLayers v.6.14.1).
[image]
[image]

The same layer display via GeoServer - everything it's ok.

[image]
[image]

How to avoid display legend on each tile at WMS layer?

Should I set additional parameter?

And what param?

I think must set it in OpenLayers code, but I don't know what.

OpenLayers Code :

```
import TileWMS from "ol/source/TileWMS";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";

// ******************source******************
const tSource = new TileWMS({
  url: "/wms_ant",
  params: {
    LAYERS: "v_glb_parcel_area",
    TILED: true,
    FORMAT_OPTIONS: "layout:bottom-left",
  },
  serverType: "geoserver",
  crossOrigin: "anonymus",
  attributions: ["REJONY: Działki (ewidencja działek)"]
});
// ******************layer******************
export const t_parcel = new TileLayer({
  source: tSource,
  visible: localStorage.getItem("działki-vi") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("działki-vi")) : false,
  opacity: localStorage.getItem("działki-op") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("działki-op")) : 1,
  title: "działki"
});
```

And Legend file on GeoServer data_dir/layouts/bottom-left.xml

```
<layout>
    <decoration type="legend" affinity="bottom,left" offset="0,0" size="auto"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: If you want a single legend at the bottom left of the viewport you would need to use ImageWMS with the `ratio` option set to 1.

Comment: ok it's slightly slower but works proper.
Thanks!

Comment: You could also request the legend separately and position it over the corner of the map.  That would allow you to use tiles, also if you rotate the view the legend will stay on the map. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wms-getlegendgraphic-forked-8bum43?file=/main.js

Comment: Yes it's very useful, thanks!